# Add dynamically created custom Angular components to layout in Nativescript

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am trying to add a dynamically created custom Angular component to a `GridLayout` in NativeScript. I know how I can dynamically add the default  non-Angular NativeScript components such a `Label` from `tns-core-modules/ui/label`, but it seems to be working different with Angular components.

I was following this [post](https://medium.com/@caroso1222/angular-pro-tip-how-to-dynamically-create-components-in-body-ba200cc289e6) which describes how to do it in pure Angular. It seems to be almost working in NativeScript but not entirely. So far I am using a template like this:

```
 <GridLayout #grid>
 </GridLayout>
```

and then in the code I am attempting something like below:

```
@ViewChild('grid') gridRef:ElementRef;

public ngAfterViewInit() {

  let grid = this.gridRef.nativeElement;
  grid.addRow(new ItemSpec(1, GridUnitType.AUTO));
  grid.addColumn(new ItemSpec(1, GridUnitType.STAR));

  let componentFactory = this.cfr.resolveComponentFactory(MyCustomComponent);
  let componentRef = componentFactory.create(this.vcr.injector, null, grid);
  componentRef.instance.myproperty = 'some value'; // pass input

  this.appRef.attachView(componentRef.hostView); // add to ng component tree for change detection

  const component = (componentRef.hostView as EmbeddedViewRef<any>).rootNodes[0];
  grid.addChild(component);
}
```

After the final step, I do see that the grid has allocated the required space that the component requires, but nothing shows. If I comment out the last step, then indeed that space that is reserved is gone. I also confirmed that the rootNodes array has only one element.

Anyone has any idea as to what I might be missing? I guess the question is how can I take an Angular view and convert it to a NativeScript view, so I can perform the `grid.addChild` and also the actions below to assign the newly created component to a specific row/column.

```
GridLayout.setRow(component,0); // fix to grid row
GridLayout.setColumn(component,index); // fix to grid column
```

How will that then work?

Thanks!